# Can I make an angularJS filter composed of multiple filters?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, filter

I'm trying to make a parameterized filter by returning an `object literal` with methods from my filter declaration. That is, I'd like to be able to do `{{ input | myFilter.foo | myFilter.bar }}`, etc... In other words, I'm trying to *namespace* my filters.

I was hoping it would just work, but I'm getting errors like:

> Unknown provider: myFilter.fooFilterProvider <- myFilter.fooFilter

I know I can pass info to a filter like `{{ input | filter:foo }}`, but as far as I can tell that only works with strings(?) and I would have to *switch* on this value, rather than just being able to directly return an object literal with methods.

#### What is the best way to approach an example like below? [(<kbd>**Plunker Demo**</kbd>)](http://plnkr.co/edit/GNGMiqCb8y3GIYLfGNny?p=preview)

```
angular.module('plunker', [])
.filter('greet', function() {
    var greetFactory = function(prefix) {
      return function(name) {
        return prefix + name + '!'
      }
    }
    return {
      hello: greetFactory('Hello'),
      wassup: greetFactory('Wassup'),
      yo: greetFactory('Yo!')
    }
});
```

---

```
<p>{{"Zach" | greet.hello}} // should output: Hello Zach!</p>
<p>{{"Bill" | greet.yo}}    // should output: Yo Bill!</p>
<p>{{"Bob" | greet.wassup}} // should output: Wassup Bob!</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can add other filters as dependencies in your filter a ssuch

```
app.filter('myFilter', ['greetFilter', function(greetFilter){

}])
```

Note that you have to add "Filter" at the end of the filter name you want to inject. You can then use those filter to build your own filter.

Comment: I may be confused, but does this allow me to use parameterized filters? I already inject dependencies into my filters (sometimes other filters), but we're still talking about creating new filters for each bit of functionality right? I'm really trying to *namespace* them is a sense. Like `input | foo.bar` and `input | foo.baz`

Comment: Mmmh, well dependency Injection kinda does that, but you can also pass variables to your filters as such `"Bob" | greet:type_of_greet` where type `type_of_greet` is any type of JS variable`